# C# bindings for a c++ library

Tags: c#, c++, .net, binding, cppsharp

I've created a c# bindings for libpostal library ([link to LibPostalNet](https://github.com/mapo80/LibPostalNet)).

I've used CppSharp to create bindings. It works but I don't how to convert this code :

```
typedef struct libpostal_address_parser_response
{
    size_t num_components;
    char** components;
    char** labels;
}
libpostal_address_parser_response_t;
```

CppSharp converts code in this way :

```
public sbyte** Components
{
    get
    {
        return (sbyte**)((global::LibPostalNet.LibpostalAddressParserResponse.__Internal*)__Instance)->components;
    }

    set
    {
        ((global::LibPostalNet.LibpostalAddressParserResponse.__Internal*)__Instance)->components = (global::System.IntPtr)value;
    }
}

public sbyte** Labels
{
    get
    {
        return (sbyte**)((global::LibPostalNet.LibpostalAddressParserResponse.__Internal*)__Instance)->labels;
    }

    set
    {
        ((global::LibPostalNet.LibpostalAddressParserResponse.__Internal*)__Instance)->labels = (global::System.IntPtr)value;
    }
}
```

Code should return a string array of num_components length.

Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complex as those is a pointer to a list of pointers of chars, something very similar to an array of strings.

You need to iterate the pointers, retrieve the internal pointers and convert those to strings (I'm assuming you can use unmanaged code):

```
libpostal_address_parser_response response = (retrieve from the library);

List<string> components = new List<string>();
List<string> labels = new List<string>();

//Not sure the name of num_components as you haven't added it to the question
//check if the name is correct
for(int buc = 0; buc < response.NumComponents; buc++)
{
    sbyte* pLabel = response.Labels[buc];
    sbyte* pComponent = response.Components[buc];

    labels.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAuto((IntPtr)pLabel));
    components.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAuto((IntPtr)pComponent));
}

//Now you have the components and the labels in their respective lists ready for usage.
```